# Wordpress API get posts by categorie

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently using the wordpress V2 API and trying to read posts based on categories. The problem I have is that in the GET request the categories are linked with OR instead of AND.

```
/v2/posts?per_page=5&page=1&categorie=1973,94&categories_exclude=1734,1032&_embed
```

This means that when I specify two categories, posts come back with only one of the two categories. I don't want that, I'm only interested in the posts that have both categories.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: define `tax_relation` as `AND` then check if it works or not.

Comment: what do you mean with tax_relation?

Comment: `tax_relation` is a REST API argument you can read more about it on documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments